# Use JSON object in angular.js

Tags: angularjs, json

Can I have some JSON object that is employes.json file for example:

```
{"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
```

And than use that object inside of a script where angular.js is? 
In other words how can I invoke predefined object in angular file and parse it?

Comment: The question is very unclear. Please add a full [mcve] that represents your situation.

Comment: this object is in json file ?

Comment: make a `$http` service call to the `json file` and on success response `parse the json` object.

Answer (score 5):

Just load it using `$http` service, for example

```
$http.get(url).then(function(response){
   // here response.data will be parsed JS object
});
```